# How to assign a changes to few associations on the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a class `Dealer` with few associations on another class:

```
class Dealer < AR::Base
  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :published_campaigns, class: 'Campaign', -> { published }
  has_many :unpublished_campaigns, class: 'Campaign', -> { unpublished }
end

class Campaign < AR::Base
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
  scope :unpublished, -> { where(published: false) }
end
```

So, there are records existing for association:

```
dealer = Dealer.first
dealer.campaigns.pluck(:id) # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
dealer.published_campaigns.pluck(:id) # => [1, 2]
dealer.unpublished_campaigns.pluck(:id) # => [3, 4]
```

I need a method which I can use for publish few campaign ids and unpublish rest of them. Something like:

```
dealer.publish_ids([2,3]) # another associated campaign_ids will become unpublished
dealer.reload
dealer.published_campaigns.pluck(:id) # => [2, 3]
dealer.unpublished_campaigns.pluck(:id) # => [1, 4]
```

Please help me with writing this method.

**Caution**: I will use this method in controller (w/ mass assignment & strong parameters), so I need to foresee the case when record wouldn't be saved (so, it seems I need something like `:autosave` in my associations)

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a form to pass the id's to the controller then a controller method something like this

```
def publish_multiple
  @dealer = Dealer.find(params[:id]) # unless you have some sort of current dealer method
  @dealer.campaigns.where(id: params[:campaign_ids]).update_all(published: true)
  @dealer.campaigns.where.not(id: params[:campaign_ids]).update_all(published: false)
end
```

Using [update all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) doesn't do validations or callbacks though.

Comment: Why do you need to save the dealer model?  You said you wanted a method to publish multiple at once, not do anything with the dealer.  If you want to do that then you can update the dealer separately and wrap everything in a transaction

Answer (score 0):

--

You'd do well to use some [ActiveRecord Association Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) with your `has_many :campaigns`:

```
#app/models/dealer.rb.
class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :campaigns do
      def publish ids
          where(id: ids).update(published: true)
          where.not(id: ids).update(published: false)
      end

      def unpublished
          where(published: false)
      end
      def published
          where(published: true)
      end
   end
end
```

This would allow you to call `@dealer.campaigns.published` & `@dealer.campaigns.unpublished` respectively.

With the above code, you'll be able to use the following:

```
@dealer = Dealer.find params[:id]
@dealer.campaigns.publish [1,2,3]
```

This will only work for the `campaigns` associated to the `dealer`.

--

If you wanted *general* campaigns, you'd be best using a class method in your `Campaign` model:

```
#app/models/campaign.rb
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.publish ids
       where(id: ids).update(published: true)
       where.not(id: ids).update(published: false)
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use: `Campaign.publish [1,2,3]`